# How can I add a background image to an input in a simple_form_for - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, associations, simple-form

I'm creating simple form in rails for create a new account, each account must has their icon. but I don't know how can I use the icon association to add in the input_html their respective icon image.

I'm trying to display the list of icons, the Icons has an url and their has a foreign key in the accounts, so I'm using this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@account], data: { account_card_target: "form" } do |f| %>
        <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :account_name %>
          <%= f.input :account_type,
                      collection: ['***', '***', '***', '***'],
                      prompt: "Select a type" %>
          <%= f.input :balance %>
          <%= f.input :account_number  %>
          <%= f.association :icon,
                as: :radio_buttons,
                label_method: ->(icon) { "<label class='icon-radio-label' for='my-input' style='background-image: url(#{cl_image_path(icon.url)})'></label>".html_safe },
                value_method: :id,
                input_html: { class: 'my-input', id: 'my-input' }
        %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

but in this code I'm adding the background to the label, and I wanna have the label empty and use the background image in the input.

If I use this I can add the bg image to the imput but i don't know how can I replace the 'saving_icon' for the icon.url, because I alerady try with lambda but still not working

```
<%= f.association :icon,
        as: :radio_buttons,
        label_method: ->(icon) { " " },
        value_method: :id,
        input_html: {
          class: "icon-radio",
          style: "background-image: url(#{cl_image_path('saving_icon')});"
        }
%>
```

any tip for achive this it'll be well received, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very well versed in simple_form, but I can give some pointers.

Unfortunately, I can't see anywhere saying that the `input_html` argument (or similar) can take a lambda in the same way as `label_method` or `value_method`.

However, I was able to find a GitHub issue for simple_form in relation to this - [see this comment in particular](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/issues/188#issuecomment-876513). It looks like HTML attributes can be included as the third array element within the `collection` argument. So you might be able to use something like this (very much untested):

```rb
f.association :icon,
  # ...
  collection: Icon.all.map do |icon|
    [
      icon.name,
      icon.id,
      { style: "background-image: url(#{cl_image_path(icon.url)})" },
    ]
  end
```

Alternatively, [defining a custom input](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#custom-inputs) looks to give you all the flexibility you'd need.

Or, with such customisation of the HTML you want generated, it might just be simpler to produce the desired HTML yourself, skipping using simple_form for this set of radio buttons.

---

I see you've added the tag `ruby-on-rails-3`. Rails 3 was [End-of-Life'd
several years ago](https://endoflife.date/rails), and so is not receiving security updates. If you are indeed still running Rails 3, I strongly advise you to upgrade.

Comment: Hey! thank you for your help, the ruby-on-rails-3 tag was my mistake sorry, I'm trying to implement your solution but I think that I'm still manipulating the label instead the html_input because I want to put the bg image in the radio buttons.

Do you know may be another way to solve it?

thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hey Zim I spend some time trying to understand your explanation and works!

<%= f.association :icon,
                        as: :radio_buttons,
                        collection: Icon.all.map { |icon| [icon.url, icon.id, style: "background-image: url(#{cl_image_path(icon.url)});"] }
        %>

This was the solution so the third parameter is the HTML of the input in the simple_form_for

thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of [ZimbiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75728776/15130477) I could solve the problem, so:

```
<%= f.association :icon,
                    as: :radio_buttons,
                    collection: Icon.all.map { |icon| [icon.url, icon.id, style: "background-image: url(#{cl_image_path(icon.url)});"] }
    %>
```

so in the collection the third argument is the HTML of the input_html, this works so good for me.